# Get number of clicks on my facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get number of clicks on my Facebook post (Image, video or audio)?
How can I do this using Facebook Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `post_engaged_users` insights metric to retrieve the number of people who clicked anywhere in your posts.
More information:

- [Graph API Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/)
- [FQL Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/)