# Number of clicks in a specific post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to get a number of clicks of a specific post?

I found this topic [Get number of clicks on my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098624/get-number-of-clicks-on-my-facebook-post), but when i do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/8062627951_10151315594152952/insights
```

OR

`https://graph.facebook.com/8062627951_10151315594152952/insights/post_engaged_users`

Even if I change the id to the App ID it returns an empty data array.

Regads,
Elkas

Comment: Are you using the access token for page 8062627951 ?

Comment: Yes. I've posted and image in the 1st answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook PHP SDK to pull that info like such:

```
$array = $facebook->api('/8062627951_10151315594152952/insights/post_engaged_users/');
```

It will include all of the proper access tokens for authorized users etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the access token for the page on which the post published to get insights data. For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/8062627951_10151315594152952/insights/post_engaged_users/&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```

Comment: @Elkas - there might be something wrong with the access token or the object IDS that you're using. First, verify that both the page ID and the post ID are correct. Then, in Graph Explorer, click on Debug (next to the access token) and see if that token is expired or if there's anything else that looks wonky.

Comment: Yes. I think the problem was not only the access_token, my mistake, but I was trying to get the number of click of a post I made. If I understand the documentation i only can get that from posts from a page or an application. Am I right? Sorry for the delayed answer, other projects come up.